# integrate smarty with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, smarty

**codeigniter version - 2.0.2**

**smarty version - 3.0.8**

Both are latest versions. I have integrated the previous versions of 2008, but I can not figure out the latest versions. Please tell me how to integrate(step by step).

Comment: Google is your friend... https://github.com/kzhiwei/codeigniter-smarty

Answer (score 4):

As [Alfonso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617054/alfonso-rubalcava) said github has an implementation of Smarty 3.0.8 and Codeigniter 2.0.2 which you can use to help you.

https://github.com/kzhiwei/codeigniter-smarty